# MVC diagrams - do they really show how MVC works?

Tags: model-view-controller

When I look at MVC diagrams I have this objection: why Controller is pictured facing user and View is hidden somewhere behind?
In my opinion user sees and interacts with View (this is what he sees in browser) and via View user "talks" to Controller, so why Controller is first in line?

Also, shouldn't diagram be shown like tower structure (instead of triangle):
View -allows user talking to- Controller - to- Model (on the bottom) - then (feed)back to- Controller -adjustment made to- View

When I see diagram with Controller facing user, I always have this strange picture of user, with a MVC diagram in one hand and screwdriver in another, popping computer's box open and looking for a Controller to get MVC started.

Comment: So the question is? http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/despat/ shows a triangle which might be as you prefer. Frankly, I don't think there should be anything onthe diagram except three boxes marked M, V, and C. And even boxes are a bit extra.

Comment: Many, MVC implementations are referred to as "front controller", because the controller is what the user is actually interacting with first. The View may be what the users *sees*, but that doesn't mean it 'does' anything.

Comment: but isn't it that user accesses Controller via View?

Comment: here is another diagram - we have another player: browser, and View is totally detached from it - View lives in browser (way I see it), here it is shown as a bystander ... like a red-riding-hood trying to get along with 7 dwarfs in one bed-time story: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/05/24/an-overview-of-php-framework-guides-for-developers/

Comment: You are putting way too much thought and effort into a meaningless distinction.

Comment: so you mean this is a loosely taken collaboration of elements, as long as you remember basics: "skinny controller", separated views and models and you are on your way ... right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really unfortunate that most articles and books still use such useless diagrams to represent MVC. A more useful diagram for MVC is actually a UML sequence diagram like Dino Esposito uses on his book [Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X)

Secondly, as you point out, most MVC articles and books have not been updated to describe how MVC is applied nowadays in web applications and still talk about MVC as it was originally envisioned 20+ years ago.

The Esposito book that I mentioned has a really good chapter about this where he describes how MVC (as originally described) is dead and we should now be focusing in modern variations of it like Model2, Passive View, and Supervising Controller. I've got a [review of this chapter on my blog](http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/The-Model-View-Controller-is-dead-long-live-the-Model-View-Controller) that you might find useful.